# Using protractor-http-mock in multiple Angular modules

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have an Angular app that needs to load configuration from the backend before it actually starts. I need to write E2E tests for the application, so that it is independent from the backend. I used `protractor-http-mock` for this purpose. Initially there was an `angular-deferred-bootstrap` module managing config dependency, but it operates before my `portal` module is fully bootstrapped, so protractor is not injecting `httpMock` module in this phase. My next decision was to turn bootstrap process into a separate module `portalBootstrap`:

```
angular
    .module('portalBootstrap', [])
    .run(['$http', '$q', '$log', '$location', ($http, $q, $log, $location) => {
        bootstrap($http, $q, $log, $location).then(config => {
            angular.module('portal').constant('conf', config);
            var injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['portal']);
        });
    }]);

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    var bootstrapElement = document.getElementById('bootstrap');
    var injector = angular.bootstrap(bootstrapElement, ['portalBootstrap']);
});
```

As I understand it, mock modules injection goes like this:

1. `addMockModule` is called and `httpMock` gets into protractor's internal mock module registry
2. `browser.get` gets invoked
3. protractor waits until angular is available and pauses its bootstrap
4. protractor injects `httpMock` into `selenium`
5. protractor calls `angular.resumeBootstrap` providing all mock modules names as argument, so the module injector is created with them.

At this point `httpMock` is accessible from the `portalBootstrap` and the `$http` requests get mocked.

The problem is now that the second module (`portal`) does not receive its copy of `httpMock` module what is quite obvious as `browser.get` is not being executed at the moment when the `portalBootstrap` receives its configuration and moves on to the `portal`.

Is it actually possible that `protractor` can inject `httpMock` into both modules? Or maybe some bootstrap architecture changes are advised?

Any hardcoding like `angular.module('portal', ['httpMock'])` should be avoided as `httpMock` is not present in non-testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bootstrap only `portal` and manually inject your `portalBootstrap`, like this:

```
angular
    .module('portalBootstrap', [])
    .run(['$http', '$q', '$log', '$location', ($http, $q, $log, $location) => {
        bootstrap($http, $q, $log, $location).then(config => {
            angular.module('portal').constant('conf', config);
            var injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['portal']);
        });
    }]);

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    var injector = angular.injector(['portalBootstrap']);
});
```

If you need to have a `$rootElement` or angular services like `$location`, you can fake a `$rootElement` like this:

```
angular
    .module('portalBootstrap', [])
    .run(['$http', '$q', '$log', '$location', ($http, $q, $log, $location) => {
        bootstrap($http, $q, $log, $location).then(config => {
            angular.module('portal').constant('conf', config);
            var injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['portal']);
        });
    }]);

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    var bootstrapElement = document.getElementById('bootstrap');
    var ngBootstrapElement = angular.element(bootstrapElement);
    angular.module('portalBootstrap').constant('$rootElement', ngBootstrapElement);
    var injector = angular.injector(['portalBootstrap']);
});
```